# Using R to merge 2 data frames that holds a column with the same name (not the "by"-variable)

Tags: r, merge

I´m trying to merge 2 data frames that looks like this.

```
DF1:      
'data.frame':   82 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ hemmabutik      : int  
 $ Sales_2016_np   : int  
 $ Sales_2016_mar  : int 



DF2:       
'data.frame':   82 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ hemmabutik      : int  
 $ Sales_2016_mar  : int



enter code here

 DF3 <- merge(x = DF1, y = DF2, by = c("hemmabutik"), all=TRUE)

DF3:     
'data.frame':   82 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ hemmabutik      : int  
 $ Sales_2016_np   : int  
 $ Sales_2016_mar.x: int  
 $ Sales_2016_mar.y: int
```

What I want is this:

```
 DF3:     
    'data.frame':   82 obs. of  4 variables:
     $ hemmabutik      : int  
     $ Sales_2016_np   : int 
     $ Sales_2016_mar: int
```

And I want that the field values for "Sales_2016_mar" in DF2 should write over the values from DF1.

Anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Please use `dput()` to share your data.

Comment: Is the variable `Sales_2016_mar` identical for both data frames? Then just use: `merge(x = DF1, y = DF2,  all=TRUE)` as the standard option of `by` is `intersect(names(x), names(y))`

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Any ideas how to let data frame y owerwrite data frame x for this merge statement?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have two data.frames, df1 and df2:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=letters[1:10], b=letters[11:20], c=LETTERS[5:14])
df2 <- data.frame(a=letters[1:10], b=letters[1:10])
```

Here is what you could do with the `merge()` function: just replace the values of `b.x` with the ones of `b.y`, rename `b.x` and drop `b.y`:

```
df3 <- merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "a", all=TRUE)
df3$b.y <- df3$b.x
df3$b.y <- NULL
colnames(df3) <- c('a','b','c')
```

Otherwise, you can use the `dplyr`package for a simpler one-line solution:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by="a") %>% transmute(a, b = b.y)
```

Comment: The problem is that the variable name is dynamic and is a different depending on what month & year it is. Therefore I´m looking for a syntax that can overwrite the common column/s name/s with the values from the right data frame.

Comment: In that case it might be worth trying to use `merge()`, then grep `.y` from the column names. That way you can grab the column name you are interested in and perform the replacement/dropping.